# Dataframe - quartile from rows

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, quartile

df:

```
a | b | c | d | q3 - q1 from (a,b,c,d) 
1 | 2 | 3 | 4 | result
5 | 6 | 2 | 7 | result
```

Can someone help me with this result?

(q -> quartile)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The quartile is the 25 % quantile, so you can use the [quantile](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.quantile.html) function along the columns axis:

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({'a': [1,5], 'b': [2,6], 'c': [3,2], 'd': [4,7]})
df['q3-q1'] = df.quantile(.75, axis=1) - df.quantile(.25, axis=1)
```

Result:

```
   a  b  c  d  q3-q1
0  1  2  3  4    1.5
1  5  6  2  7    2.0
```